# How do I call a function that prints a string variable which is defined in another function?

Tags: python

So here's my code up till now:

```
age = input("Enter Age: ")


def agePrint():
    print("You have entered " + age + ", which places you in " + ageGroup)

def ageFinder():
    if 00 <= int(age) <= 14:
        ageGroup = "Children"
        agePrint()
    elif 15 <= int(age) <= 24:
        ageGroup = "Youth"
        agePrint()

ageFinder()
```

So What I want is instead of writing the agePrint function manually for every age group, I just call a function, but the thing is the age group changes for every, well, agegroup. So I have to put it in the function as a variable, but when i call agePrint it says that ageGroup isn't defined. So how do I define the variable in such a way that it prints the suitable age group?

Comment: I think you need parameters for your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `age` and `ageGroup` as parameters:

```
def agePrint(age, ageGroup):
    print("You have entered " + age + ", which places you in " + ageGroup)

def ageFinder():
    age = input("Enter Age: ")
    if 00 <= int(age) <= 14:
        ageGroup = "Children"
        agePrint(age, ageGroup)
    elif 15 <= int(age) <= 24:
        ageGroup = "Youth"
        agePrint(age, ageGroup)

ageFinder()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the age group as a parameter to the function:

```
def agePrint(ageGroup):
    print("You have entered " + age + ", which places you in " + ageGroup)

    if 00 <= int(age) <= 14:
        agePrint("Children")
    elif 15 <= int(age) <= 24:
        agePrint("Youth")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass ageGroup parameter to `agePrint()` function.

```
def agePrint(ageGroup):
    print("You have entered " + age + ", which places you in " + ageGroup)

def ageFinder():
    if 00 <= int(age) <= 14:
        ageGroup = "Children"
    elif 15 <= int(age) <= 24:
        ageGroup = "Youth"
    agePrint(ageGroup)//Call the agePrint() function out of if block.
    
age = input("Enter Age: ")
ageFinder()
```

And also, there is no need to call agePrint() function seperately for if-elif block. You can assign a value to ageGroup and call function after that.